# Finding calculation in Crystal Report field?

Tags: database, crystal-reports, report, formula

I am very new to Crystal Reports and I have a crystal report that I am trying to edit and see how it is pulling certain values for specific fields.

When the report is run, the field populates with a number, but when I open it in Crystal Report in the Design view, that field is blank without any type of formula inside it, so I'm not sure where it's doing its calculation from.

[image]

I have attached a snip to show what I mean. As you can see, many fields have a formula in them, but also all of the blank fields there actually also populate with a value when the report is run so I'm needing to know how these fields are getting their numbers when I don't see any formula or anything currently in them when in Design mode.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that the fields/frmula are in a higher report section that is set to 'Underlay Following Sections.'
You can find out by right-clicking the sections, and selecting 'Section Expert'
Find a section where the checkbox for 'Underlay Following Sections' is turned on.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, I tried checking what you recommended and it seems that all sections have that box unchecked though.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to File > Export > Export Report > Report Definition.

It will export a .txt file which shows where all the fields on the report are coming from.

Comment: I also had tried this, but it doesn’t show any formula or where the calculations are coming from.